# How to read csv file in R?

Tags: r

http://www.aihw.gov.au/acim-books/ , 'lung cancer'

The above link takes you to a XLS file, table with data of people with lung cancer. I would like to read this data in R.

I have already saved the above data as 'lung cancer.csv' in my desktop.

How do i do this?

I've got:

```
data <- read.csv(file="lung cancer.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

but it says

> ```
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
>   cannot open file 'lung cancer.csv': No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: maybe you should download the file in your working directory or provide the complete URL to the file...

Comment: Make sure the csv file is in your R working directory.  If it is on your desktop, it probably isn't!

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597536/error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection-cannot-open-file-specd

Comment: The files on your webpage are xml files.  You need to save them as csv files.

Comment: how can i download the file in my working directory? because the file is in the desktop...

Comment: Make sure `lung cancer.csv` is in the path from `getwd()`.

Comment: got it! Now i just need to get a histogram on this data. Don't know why it isnt working! Here's my code:

Comment: getwd("lung cancer.csv")                                                                                        data <- read.csv(C:\Users\Heramba\Desktop\lung cancer.csv', header=T)    data <- as.numeric(levels(data))[data]                                                                  class(data)                                                                                                      hist(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the absolute path of the .csv file.
eg. Desktop:\R\lung_cancer.csv
*Also use double\ instead of \ or use /* .

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide full path to your file, for example:

```
 datos <- read.csv("C:/Users/F553MA/Desktop/muestreo.csv")
```